# Simple example for client side validation in a windows store app using DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, data-annotations

Can anybody come up with a simple example for a client side validation of a textbox using dataannotations.  {xaml and C#}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is already possible with windows phone using data annotations.
Maybe try this alternative approach using FluentValidation : http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2013/12/02/.aspx